# MVC Telerik-Grid dynamic generating grid columns and edit inline

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik

I want to build one template with telerik grid, which is invoking by other page as an partial view.
the template code like this:

```
 @model IEnumerable<object>
 @using System.Collections;
 @using System.Collections.Generic;
@using System.Reflection;

@{
ViewBag.Title = "UserView2";
}

<div>
@{Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
      .Name("UserConfiguration")
      .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(o => o.GetType().GetProperty("ConfigurationItemId").GetValue(o)))
      .Columns(
      columns =>
      {


          Type t = Model.GetType().GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault();
          foreach (var prop in t.GetProperties())
          {

                  columns.Bound(prop.PropertyType, prop.Name);

          }

          columns.Command(commands => commands.Edit()).Width(100);

      }
      )
      .DataBinding(
      dataBinding => dataBinding.Server()
      .Update("UpdateUser", "Configuration")
      )
        .Pageable(paging => paging.PageSize(20))
        .Sortable()
        .Scrollable(o => o.Height(500))
        .Filterable()
        .Resizable(resizing => resizing.Columns(true))
        .Render();        
}
```

The other view page Invoke the template view like this:
       @Html.Partial("UserView2", Model.UserList)

And when i run it, the page open successfully and display all the data successfully. so i think it works well through reflecting get the columns name and columns data. But when i click "Edit" button, it will throw an exception:

Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

anyone can help me solve this?